# Date.strptime throwing invalid date for "%Y%W" format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, strptime, strftime

My date = 1st January, 2015.
I did 
`date_formatted = date.strftime('%Y%W')` which returned "201500"

Then when am trying to do `Date.strptime(date_formatted, '%Y%W')` it's throwing an invalid date error even though the original string was returned from strptime's counterpart srftime.

Comment: What language are you writing this in ? You may want to tag your question with the language.

Comment: @steveb The language is ruby on rails. Ruby to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. `Time.strptime(date_formatted, '%Y%W')` is what will work here.